# Parse iOS SDK: strange "cannot do a comparison query of type: (NULL)"

Tags: ios, parse-platform

**Scenario**

I have been using the parse.com framework for over 6 months now on a project. It seems like it is very glitchy and full of bugs but this is something that I need to know if I'm doing it the right way. I am trying to use a PFQueryTableViewController to display similar user's info to a user. I use the code...

```
-(PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    PFQuery *matchQuery = [PFUser query];
    [matchQuery whereKey:@"mostCommon" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser][@"mostCommon"]];
    [matchQuery whereKey:@"userID" notEqualTo:currentUserID];
    return matchQuery;

}
```

**Problem**

When I run this and try to push this PFQTVC onto the stack, I get this error message...

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)'
```

This is usually to do with not having your information set in the database. I am providing the image below to illustrate there **IS** indeed data in the data browser.

[image]

**Question**

So if the query is correct, and the data is there... **THEN WHY IS THE APP CRASHING**?

Comment: Is "userID" an actual column in the user table?

Comment: Yes it is. I put breakpoints in the code above and it crashes after the "[matchQuery whereKey:@"mostCommon" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser][@"mostCommon"]];" line of code. For some reason it just does not like that. But I have zero idea why.

Comment: Can you NSLog(@"%@", [PFUser currentUser]);

Comment: Whao! You are on to something... I logged out the current user and the "mostCommon" field is NOT there!... This is really weird. Because it is set in the data browser on parse.com. What gives? Why is it not showing up when I query from the device?

Comment: If there's no current user, there's no object for there to be a mostCommon field on would there?

Comment: True, but that is not what happened. I logged out the current user and got all of the current user's info (userID, profile info, picture file) except for the "mostCommon" key. It doesn't exist. But if you look in my question, I provide a picture showing that is **does** exist... *confused*.

Comment: I'm confused, is there a user logged in or not, when you get the error?

Comment: `[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"mostCommon"];` You have to use `objectForKey:`

Comment: @TomErikStower yes there is a user logged in, but the key "mostCommon" (although I proved that it does exist on the user object) doesn't appear in the query for the user object.

Comment: @Dehli thank you for your suggestion. I unfortunately just tried that and it did not make a difference. I think I narrowed down what the problem is now. It is that when I query from my device for the user, a certain key ("mostCommon") is not "showing up" in the query. It returns every bit of information of the user except for that key. You know why that could be?

Comment: It might be that you need to fetch the user object first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem you have is that in order to access the value for an object's key, you must use `objectForKey:` In your code, you use bracket notation which doesn't work with Parse objects.

```
[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"mostCommon"];
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I unfortunately just tried that and it did not make a difference. I think I narrowed down what the problem is now. It is that when I query from my device for the user, a certain key ("mostCommon") is not "showing up" in the query. It returns every bit of information of the user except for that key. You know why that could be?

Comment: What happens if you do this: `NSLog(@"%@", [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"mostCommon"]);`

Comment: As it turned I had to delete that column in the data browser on parse.com and just create a new column called "common" and now it works great. Just some parse glitch I supposed. I'll give you a check for pointing me in the right direction.