# querying an array on Parse (swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have a class **"MeetUps"**
and in it, there are these columns:

1. "**peeps**" - an array of usernames
2. "**when**" - with a value of Date
3. "**objectId**" - the objectId of the group

**I'm trying to get the values of the column "when" and "objectId" if a user's username is found in the array "peeps"**

This is my code:

```
func getDisplayedGroups() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "MeetUps")
    query.whereKey("peeps", contains: (PFUser.current()?.username))
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else if let objects = objects {
            for meetUps in objects {
                let id = meetUps["objectId"]
                let date = meetUps["when"]
                print(id)
                print(date)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it runs, but it prints out nil - which is puzzling because I've checked the parse dashboard and those values are not nil.

looking at the parse's documentation on [querying on array values](https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/ios/guide/#queries-on-array-values),
it suggests i use this method instead:

```
    query.whereKey("peeps", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.username))
```

however, this method results in a crash, and the error says: *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: _SwiftValue'*

please advise. Thank you!

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941335/parse-ios-sdk-strange-cannot-do-a-comparison-query-of-type-null

Comment: Is meetUps.objectId also nil?

Comment: @LoVo i think the issue he is facing is different from mine. for one, he is trying to query string values. which i have no problem with. secondly, his questions isn't resolved as he has mentioned in his comments. thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: @xpereta yes, both prints nil :(

Comment: When you added a breakpoint inside the for loop and inspected both object and meetUp, what did you see?

Comment: Did you checked if the PFUser.current()?.username is set and exists in the peeps array?

Comment: @LoVo, yes i have.

Comment: @xpereta Thanks for your suggestion. I must have a typo error somewhere, because retyping the code in solved the issue. Still many thanks for responding!